# How to correctly pass parameters to useCallback() hook?

Tags: reactjs

Console warning “**React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'animate'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.** "

If the animate function is set in brackets

```
return () => {cancelAnimationFrame (refAnimation.current)}}, [animate])
```

It gives another warning "**The 'animate' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook change on every render. To fix this, wrap the definition of 'animate' in its own useCallback () Hook.**"

I try to wrap the function in the **useCacllback hook**, but apparently I'm doing it wrong and I get an error:

**React Hook useCallback does nothing when called with only one argument. Did you forget to pass an array of dependencies?**

```
const animate = useCallback(() => {
   refAnimation.current = requestAnimationFrame(() =>
   animate(cur, rez, speed)
);
   cur = cur + speed;
   ref.current.style.marginLeft = cur.toFixed(2) + "px";

   if (Math.round(cur) === rez) {
   cancelAnimationFrame(refAnimation.current);
}
```

});

I can't figure out how to correctly pass parameters to the **useCallback()** to pass them further to **animate()**?

Full version of the code  https://codesandbox.io/s/old-frog-6nwfq?file=/src/scroll.js

```js
  let ref = useRef();
  let refAnimation = useRef();

  ...

  const animate = (cur, rez, speed) => {
    refAnimation.current = requestAnimationFrame(() =>
      animate(cur, rez, speed)
    );
    cur = cur + speed;
    ref.current.style.marginLeft = cur.toFixed(2) + "px";
    if (Math.round(cur) === rez) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(refAnimation.current);
    }
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current === true) {
      refAnimation.current = requestAnimationFrame(() => animate(0, 0, 0));
    }
    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(refAnimation.current);
    };
  }, [animate]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `useCallback` you are memoizing that callback based on some parameters. Here you haven't specified any parameter. If that's not the case and it should be created just once (and not to be re-created based on a change in some other values/states), you have to pass an empty array as the second argument to `useCallback`. It causes this callback to be created just once, when component mounts.
Take a look at the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: I try to do this, but I get the "**cur is not defined**" error. That is, in theory, I did not pass the cur and rez parameters to the function.  `const animate = useCallback(() => {
    refAnimation.current = requestAnimationFrame(() =>
      animate(cur, rez, speed)
    );

    cur = cur + speed;

    ref.current.style.marginLeft = cur.toFixed(2) + "px";

    if (Math.round(cur) === rez) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(refAnimation.current);
    }
  },[cur, rez]);`

Comment: Just add them as arguments in the callback you are passing to useCallback